# Append param on loop javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function that has a `menu` param

```
removeChildCheck:function(menu){
    let removeArrayValues = [];
       for(var i=0; i < this.checkbox.menu.length; i++){
           removeArrayValues.push(this.checkbox.menu[i].value);
       }
       this.user.permissions = this.user.permissions.filter((i) => !removeArrayValues.includes(i));
 },
```

when I used it like this `removeChildCheck('dashboard')` im getting length of undefined.

How can I append the `param` and loop on it? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to do:

```
this.checkbox[menu]
```

That is, access the property of `checkbox` that has the name stored in the variable `menu`? Keep in mind that:

```
this.checkbox.dashboard
```

is equivalent to

```
this.checkbox['dashboard']
```

and

```
menu = 'dashboard'
this.checkbox[menu]
```

Answer (score 1):

As audiodude says, use array syntax: this.**checkbox[menu]**.length

```
removeChildCheck:function(menu){
    let removeArrayValues = [];
       for(var i=0; i < this.checkbox[menu].length; i++){
           removeArrayValues.push(this.checkbox[menu][i].value);
       }
       this.user.permissions = this.user.permissions.filter((i) => !removeArrayValues.includes(i));
 },
```